# Evaluate $\int_{.5}^{1} \frac{1}{(\cos^2(\pi u))^d} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1} du$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Closed form ( special functions are allowed) for following integrals.

**1)**$$I_{c}(a)=cte *\int_{.5}^{1} \frac{1}{(\cos^2(\pi u))^d} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1} du$$

**2)**$$J_{c}(a)= cte * \int_{0}^{.5} \frac{1}{(\cos^2(\pi u))^d} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} u^{a-1} du$$

where $cte =\frac{1}{\Gamma(d)2^d}$.(you can ignore $cte$ part)

Simulation studies confirm that $I_{c}(a)$ and $J_{c}(a)$ exist.

**R code**

```
 a<<-3;cc<<-1;d<<-5
 fn<-function(u){
 temp.e<-(cc^2)/((2*cos(pi*u))^2)
 temp.m<-1/((cos(pi*u))^2)
 cte<-gamma(d)*(2^d)
 ret.value<-(temp.m^d)*exp(-temp.e)*u^(a-1)/cte
 return(ret.value)
 }
 integrate(fn,lower=.501,upper=1)
 # output 
 #> integrate(fn,lower=.51,upper=1)
 #0.438016 with absolute error < 6.9e-08
```

I think , there is no closed form unless if special functions are allowed.

All my try:

a)if I find a Taylor series for $\frac{1}{(\cos^2(\pi u))^d} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}} $ like
$$\frac{1}{(\cos^2(\pi u))^d} e^{-\frac{c^2}{2\cos^2(\pi u)}}=\sum \frac{a_n}{n!}u^n$$ 
so it will help since
$$I_{c}(a)= \sum \frac{a_n}{n!} \int_{0}^{.5} u^{n+a-1} du$$

b)I think about change variable like $t=\cos^2(\pi u)$ or $t=\frac{1}{\cos^2(\pi u)}$ but I can not handle it.

3) I know 
$cos(\pi u)=\frac{e^{i\pi u}+e^{- i \pi u}}{2}$
 but I am not with familiar this type of integrals.

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Comment: @mrtaurho, Thank you for edit.